# Remove extended function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**How to get rid of extended** `$.extend()` **function from a specific target object**. Example: By reloading parts of the DOM with XHR, I'm able to detect the appearance of the object like this:

```
// Initliaize:
$('#sausage').catsup();
    ...
// Inside fn.catsup():
if($('body').find($(this)).size() == 0) // object has gone
```

But how can I kill `fn.catsup()`? This seems not to work:

```
$(this).clearQueue();
$(this).stop();
$(this).unbind();
delete $(this);
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'kill catsup()'?

Comment: @msec. Now I'm even more confused, what are you trying to do? Can you give us the context? it's very hard to understand the question.

Comment: If you want a way to "destroy" the actions done by `catsup` you will have to write another function (even better add a method to catsup itself) that will do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood the question, you want to remove your function from jQuery.

use this:

```
$.fn.catsup = null;
```

Or as suggested by [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905699/jquery-remove-extended-function/9905808#comment12638831_9905808):

```
delete $.fn.catsup
```

Comment: `delete $.fn.catsup` might be more appropriate... it'll make `jQuery.fn` seem like it *never* had the `catsup` property (`jQuery.fn.hasOwnProperty('catsup')` would return true if set to `null`, but false if `delete` was used).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I understood it wrongly, you simply want `catsup` to not be part of jQuery extension functions anymore:

```
delete $.fn.catsup;
```

Note that this will <del>not</del> affect all jQuery DOM objects, i.e. both existing ones and those created afterwards.

Comment: Since `$.fn` is an alias for `jQuery.prototype`, this **will** affect existing jQuery objects.

Comment: Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dKBmt/) it will affect **all** jQuery objects.

Comment: That's indeed the case - thanks for correction. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: what if i want just  remove it from object